# replace and remove duplicate rows using ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, duplicates

I have a data frame of postcodes with a regional/metro classification assigned. In some instances, due to the datasource, the same postcode will occur with both a regional and metro classification.

```r
  POSTCODE   REGON  
1     3000    METRO       
2     3000    REGIONAL      
3     3256    METRO     
4     3145    METRO
```

I am wondering how to remove the duplicate row and replace the region with "SPLIT" in these instances.

I have tried using the below code however this reassignes the entire dataset with either "METRO" or "REGIONAL"

```r
test <- within(PC_ACTM, REGION <- ifelse(duplicated("Postcode"), "SPLIT", REGION))
```

The desired output would be

```r
  POSTCODE   REGON  
1     3000    SPLIT
2     3256    METRO     
3     3145    METRO
```

Example data:

```
dput(PC_ACTM)
structure(list(POSTCODE = c(3000L, 3000L, 3256L, 3145L), REGON = c("METRO", 
"REGIONAL", "METRO", "METRO")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: You're passing a string in `duplicated("Postcode")` where you should be using `duplicated(POSTCODE)`.  Be aware also that R is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks!! I've now got it to replace one of the instances with "SPLIT". However, now i have both a "REGIONAL/METRO" and "SPLIT" entry for these postcodes, how might i go about retaining inly the SPLIT entry? keeping in mind i also need to retain other "METRO/REGIONAL" entries where no duplication in postcode occurs. @RitchieSacramento

Comment: Best to edit your question and provide a minimal complete example of your data and expected output.

Comment: The desired output is now included @RitchieSacramento

Comment: Try `aggregate(REGION ~ POSTCODE, PC_ACTM, FUN = \(x) if (length(unique(x)) > 1) "SPLIT" else x[1])` - this will de-duplicate and recode duplicates that have different region values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your title, you're looking for an `ifelse()` solution; perhaps this will suit?

```r
PC_ACTM <- structure(list(POSTCODE = c(3000L, 3000L, 3256L, 3145L),
                          REGION = c("METRO", "REGIONAL", "METRO", "METRO")),
                     class = "data.frame",
                     row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))

PC_ACTM$REGION <- ifelse(duplicated(PC_ACTM$POSTCODE), "SPLIT", PC_ACTM$REGION)
PC_ACTM[!duplicated(PC_ACTM$POSTCODE, fromLast = TRUE),]
#>   POSTCODE REGION
#> 2     3000  SPLIT
#> 3     3256  METRO
#> 4     3145  METRO
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I did mean that, thank you! Also, I just saw your comment above with `aggregate()` which I think is a better approach; are you going to post that as an answer @RitchieSacramento?

Answer (score 0):

Consider `ave` to sequential count by group and then `subset` the last but before use `ifslse` to replace needed value for any group counts over 1. Below uses new base R 4.1.0+ pipe `|>`:

```r
test <- within(
    PC_ACTM, {
        PC_SEQ <- ave(1:nrow(test), POSTCODE, FUN=seq_along)
        PC_COUNT <- ave(1:nrow(test), POSTCODE, FUN=length)
        REGION <- ifelse(
            (PC_SEQ == PC_COUNT) & (PC_COUNT > 1), "SPLIT", REGION
        )
    }
) |> subset(
    subset = PC_SEQ == PC_COUNT,   # SUBSET ROWS
    select = c(POSTCODE, REGION)   # SELECT COLUMNS
) |> `row.names<-`(NULL)           # RESET ROW NAMES
```